# How to return the result of for loop count using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using below code to compare each value from the string i have given and if any of the character matches with 4 i need the total matching occurrences for it.

I have tried the below snipped but i am getting only 0, can any one check and advise , where i went wrong?

```
       def wordcount(list):    
count=0
values=[]
for i in range (len(list)):
    if int(list[i])==4:
        print("the value taken from the loop is: ",list[i])
        print("comparison result is: ",list[i]==4)
        count=count+1
        print("match count=",count)
        values.append(count)
        return values
    else:
        values.append(count)
        return values
   # return count
```

print(wordcount("1452454878594521564"))

expecting 5 as count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work is because once `return` statement is executed, the loop will not execute again. The control will be out of the function. Here's how you can fix your code:

```
def wordcount(l):    
    count=0
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if int(l[i])==4:
            count=count+1
    return count
print(wordcount("1452454878594521564"))
```

I removed the empty values list because honestly, I didn't see the purpose of it.

Also, if you want to count a particular character in a string just use the count method:

`print("1452454878594521564".count('4'))`

Answer (score 0):

The result your getting is correct in case you want to find out if an item was repeated 4 times in the string. The below code will demonstrate how many times an item occurred repeatedly 4 times or over:

```
def wordcount(list):    
    count=0
    values=[]
    for item in list:
        innercount=0
        for initem in list:
            if item == initem:
                innercount=innercount+1
        if innercount >=4:
            count=count+1
            values.append([item,innercount])
        #list = list.replace(item, "")      
    return values, count
```

If you want a unique occurrence un-hash the commented line.